# Creating nuget package that can be consumed in squirrel.windows

Tags: .net, windows, nuget, .net-4.5, clickonce

We have a windows app that currently uses ClickOnce deployment for app publish and updating, we had some issues with it which were solved by Squirrel.windows https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows

In ClickOnce we had set the pre-requisites download from our directory and not from internet, as the app will be used in a local environment, so it installs framework 4.5 and vc++ redistributables when not already installed in target machine

Now Since squirrel simply creates a setup for the nuget package, my main question arrives is it possible to add such redistributables and framework components to nuget package so the app can install when there is no internet connection.

I am not sure if it is possible or not, any advice is appriciated

Comment: did you solve your issue?